# AWS Api Gateway dont find routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a API running in a container inside AWS ECS, being exposed through a Load Balancer. I've tried to put it in a API Gateway, setting the "root" route of the API on the Gateway integration, but when requesting it, it always return "not found"

Comment: can you please provide more information?
integration of api gateway? ecs configs etc?